# question on MVC in objective c

Tags: objective-c, model-view-controller

in objective c, following MVC pattern we have:
- VIEW = UIView subclass
- CONTROLLER = UIViewController subclass
- MODEL = data for tableview ecc

instead generic classes that make operations and compute our data in which category can be inserted? MODEL? or what else?

Answer (score 0):

The model classes are not just the data behind the table view, they are all the classes modeling the problem you want to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking what classes can be used as model objects? There are quite a few... NS[Mutable]Dictionary, NS[Mutable]Array, NS[Mutable]Set, NS[Mutable]String, NSManagedObject, and so on. NSFetchedResultsController and NSManagedObjectContext both fit into a sort of model controller role. Often, though, a significant portion of your application's functionality is in the model, and it makes sense for the object that manages the data to be a class of your own creation.